# Android (Java): browsing list (e.g. RecyclerView) by left and right swipe, one by one

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, swipe

Does anyone know how to do a list browsing (e.g. `RecyclerView`), where each element of the list fills the entire screen, and the transition to the next / previous element is to be done by swipe left / right?
Something like this: [image: Reference image]

Best regards.

Comment: You are looking for a `ViewPager`. Not list with `RecyclerView`.

Comment: You can use viewPager for this purpose instead of recycler view.Something like banner slider

Answer (score 0):

You need ViewPager for this
Check this link
https://www.journaldev.com/10096/android-viewpager-example-tutorial

There are many more links that can help you in this case. Search for ViewPager

Comment: I implement ViewPager2 based on https://proandroiddev.com/look-deep-into-viewpager2-13eb8e06e419. :-)
Thank you very much for all answers.